# Whose blood did Manasseh shed in Jerusalem & why?

Tags: malchut-royalty, melachim-kings-book-of, murder, yehuda

I ask this question based on the below verses that indicate that G-d punished Judah because of the sins of Manasseh.

Are there some scriptures / texts where I can find more details?

> **[2 Kings 21:16](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.21.16?lang=bi)** Moreover, Manasseh shed very much innocent blood, until he filled Jerusalem from one end to the other, besides his sin that he caused Judah to commit, to do what was evil in the eyes of the Lord.

> **[2 Kings 23:26](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.23.26?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)** Nevertheless, the Lord did not turn back from His great wrath, for His wrath was kindled against Judah, because of all the provocations that Manasseh had provoked Him. **27** And the Lord said, "I will remove Judah too from before Me as I have removed Israel and I will reject this city, which I have chosen- Jerusalem-and the Temple concerning which I said, 'My Name shall be there.' "

> **[2 Kings 24:3](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.24.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)** Indeed, it was by the order of the Lord against Judah to remove them from before Him, because of the sins of Manasseh, according to all that he had done. **4** And also [because of] the innocent blood that he had shed, and he filled Jerusalem with innocent blood and the Lord did not want to forgive.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yeddu and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: My impressions of the verses were that he killed whomever he felt like killing.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the commentators ([Radak](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Kings.21.16?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_II_Kings.21.16.1&lang2=bi), [Ralbag](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Kings.24.4?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Ralbag_on_II_Kings.24.4.1&lang2=bi) and [Chomat Anach](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Kings.21.16?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Chomat_Anakh_on_II_Kings.21.16.1&lang2=bi)) say this term may refer to Menashe having killed the prophet Yesha'ayahu, per the Talmud in [Yevamot 49b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yevamot.49b.6?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi).

Elsewhere [Ralbag](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Kings.21.16?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Ralbag_on_II_Kings.21.16.1&lang2=bi) wrote that he thinks it refers to the people who weren't willing to go along with Menashe's idolatrous reforms, including prophets. Some of the prophets of his era are referred to [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Chronicles.33.18-19?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi).